# RestFb Fetch Events

Tags: facebook, restfb

I'm trying to fetch events from a public page, i tried a lot of methods:

Method One:

```
Connection<Event> myFeed = fbClient.fetchConnection(pageID+"/events", Event.class);
List<Event> abc = myFeed.getData();

for (List<Event> myFeedConnectionPage : myFeed) {
    for (Event post : myFeedConnectionPage) {
        System.out.println("ABC " + post.getName());
    }
}
```

Method Two:

```
Connection <Event> myEventDescription = fbClient.fetchConnection (pageID+"/events", Event.class, Parameter.with ("Fields", "name, description"));
for (Event e : myEventDescription.getData()) {
    System.out.println("ABC1 " + e.toString());
}
```

Method Three:

```
Event event = fbClient.fetchObject(pageID+"/events", Event.class);
System.out.println(event.toString());
```

Method Four:

```
Connection<JsonObject> eventListConnection = fbClient.fetchConnection("164788810237714/events", 
                    JsonObject.class);
    while (eventListConnection.hasNext()) {
        for (List<JsonObject> eventConnectionPage : eventListConnection) {
             for (JsonObject test : eventConnectionPage) {
                  System.out.println("ABC3 " + test.toString());
             }
        }
    }
```

Nothing seems to work, its either null or empty or doesnt pass the sys out. But when i ran it in facebook graph.  I can get the data I need:

```
164788810237714/events?fields=id,name
{
    "data": [
      {
         "id": "594948540530494",
         "name": "BSN Putrajaya Night Marathon 2013"
      },
      {
         "id": "656503507700225",
         "name": "Pelancaran School Bank"
      },
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Already tried to add the fields Paramter as you do in the Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Yes and still the same.  Doesn't pass to any sys out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding the version:

```
new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken(), Version.VERSION_2_6);
```

It seems version 2.7 can't extract the data for events but 2.6 works.